# Как выловить POST запрос из потока ServerSocket

Tags: java, сокет

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким способом можно прочитать POST запрос отправленный браузером на сервер, если сервер написан на сокетах. Проблема в том, что зависает цикл. И никакими способами его не получается остановить. Пытался останавливать когда длина строки была равна 0. Пытался считывать Content-Length значение и в цикле for читать BufferedReader ом, null и -1 вообще не ловит потому, что соединение не закрывается, а сокет ждет ответа от сервера. Как быть подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Принимаю от браузера Content-Length. Запускаю`while(true){ BufferedReader.readLine();}`  обрываю цикл когда длина строки = 0; Дальше запускаю второй цикл `for(int i = 0; i<contentLength;/** Именно меньше, а не меньше или равно**/ i++){int ch = BufferedReader.read();/**Это ключевой момент. }`  Таким образом получается идеально читать пост параметры из серверного сокета.